# How can I access iteration index in Ramda.map

Tags: javascript, mapping, lodash, ramda.js

I used to write something like

```
_.map(items, (item, index) => {});
```

with lodash. Usually I don't need `index` but sometimes it's useful.

I'm migrating to Ramda now:

```
R.map((item, index) => {}, items);
```

`index` is `undefined`. Sure, I can create variable `index` in upper scope and increment it every time in `map` body but it's kinda wrong from FP point of view that Ramda stands for. So is there's any build in way of getting iteration index?

Comment: There is "See also" in documentation that can help you with such questions

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Check out [`addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#addIndex):

> Creates a new list iteration function from an existing one by adding two new parameters to its callback function: the current index, and the entire list.
>
> This would turn, for instance, Ramda's simple map function into one that more closely resembles Array.prototype.map. Note that this will only work for functions in which the iteration callback function is the first parameter, and where the list is the last parameter. (This latter might be unimportant if the list parameter is not used.)

Example from the docs:

```
var mapIndexed = R.addIndex(R.map);
mapIndexed((val, idx) => idx + '-' + val, ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']);
//=> ['0-f', '1-o', '2-o', '3-b', '4-a', '5-r']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [mapIndexed](https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.6.0/RA.html#.mapIndexed) from [Ramda Adjunct](https://github.com/char0n/ramda-adjunct) which uses `R.addIndex` under the hood.

> R.map function that more closely resembles Array.prototype.map. It takes two new parameters to its callback function: the current index, and the entire list.

```
RA.mapIndexed((val, idx, list) => idx + '-' + val, ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']);
//=> ['0-f', '1-o', '2-o', '3-b', '4-a', '5-r']
```

It also offsers a [reduceIndexed](https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.6.0/RA.html#.reduceIndexed)

```
const initialList = ['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r'];

reduceIndexed((acc, val, idx, list) => acc + '-' + val + idx, '', initialList);
//=> "-f0-o1-o2-b3-a4-r5"
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `addIndex` you could use `toPairs` before mapping, from [the documentation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs):

> Converts an object into an array of key, value arrays. Only the object's own properties are used. Note that the order of the output array is not guaranteed to be consistent across different JS platforms.

The documentation talks only about objects but it works equally well with arrays. In your example:

```
R.map(([index, item]) => {}, R.toPairs(items));

// or, equivalent:

R.compose(
    R.map(([index, item]) => {}),
    R.toPairs,
)(items)
```

Bear in mind that in each index/value pair the index is always the first element, so the order is reversed compared to lodash (or the native `Array.prototype.map`).