# How can I access iteration array in Ramda.map?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Similar to [How can I access iteration index in Ramda.map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36573832/3942699) except I'd like to have access to the array instead.

`Array.prototype.map` accepts `(item, index, arr) => {}`. How can I access `arr` in `Ramda.map`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked question quotes the Ramda documentation for [`addIndex`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) pointing out that it

> Creates a new list iteration function from an existing one by adding two new parameters to its callback function: the current index, and the entire list.

So the entire list is already supplied to your function when you use `addIndex`.